# Add/Remove .append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Ready, Pause, Play script going here so there are a couple other widget.binds for those. In my .PLAY block below I add in the songs titles via widget.getsounds so when they click play they appear from the append. How can I remove the append when they click another?

Or more simply how do I remove .appends regardless of whether or not is for this specific purpose?

```
widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function () {
    $("#{STORIES.story_id}6 :image")
        .removeClass('buy')
        .removeClass('buyyy')
        .addClass('buyy');
    widget.getSounds(function (sound) {
        var a = sound.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            $('#trackinfo').append($('<span>', {
                text: sound[i].title
            }));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the :last-child selector to find the last thing you appended, then remove it:

```
$('#trackinfo:last-child').remove();
```